# How to add contents to the array dynamically in plsql

Tags: sql, plsql

**Unable to store values in to 'names' array.Please help me to resolve the error.**

```
declare 
type name is varray(50) of varchar2(10);
abc varchar2(50);
names name:=name();
begin
    for i in 0..4
    loop
        select cname into abc from customer where cid=1;
        names(i):=abc;
        dbms_output.put_line(names(i));
    end loop;
end;
```

I am new to pl/sql and I am trying to add elements to my array but I am getting some error as follows.

> ORA-06532: Subscript outside of limit

Comment: In PL/SQL index starts from 1 and before you add a new element to an empty VARRAY you have to extend it, Use EXTEND to do so.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! Got the output :) !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop in PL/SQL needs to start with 1.

Also, before saving value, you need to `extend` the record variable.

Also, your type is `varray(50) of VARCHAR2(10)`, whereas `abc` is variable of size 50.

```
declare 
    type name is varray(50) of varchar2(50);
    abc varchar2(50);
    names name:=name();
begin
    for i in 1..4
    loop
        select cname into abc from customer where cid=1;
        names.extend(1);
        names(i):=abc;
        dbms_output.put_line(names(i));
    end loop;
end;
```

Why do you need to `EXTEND` - [Standard Oracle DOC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare 
    type name is varray(50) of varchar2(10);
    abc varchar2(50);
    names name:=name();
    begin
        for i in 1..4
        loop
            select cname into abc from customer where cid=1;
            names.extend;
            names(i):=abc;
            dbms_output.put_line(names(i));
        end loop;

end;
```

1) Arrays start from 1.

2)  `type name is varray(50) of varchar2(10);` means that max length of array is 50 is not connected with  initial length.